# How fix 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403'?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

The JavaScripts didn't load even though I can open it directly via web browser.

- I want to import product in my WooCommerce site using builtin import functionality.
- When I run the importer, the progress bar doesn't move even though I only imported 1 row of product.
- After I open the console, there are error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 "when loading the wc-product-import.min.js. But, I can open the script directly when I use "Open in new Tab".

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

a 403 HTTP status error indicates that the request was understood, but will not fullfill the request because the requested asset is 'forbidden'.

This is most likely an issue with your .htaccess file, or a permissions issue within your wordpress installation. Try to delete the .htaccess file that is in your root folder. Then, log in to your wordpress dashboard, go to `Settings` -> `Permalinks`, and then just simply click Save Changes. This will generate a new .htaccess for your wordpress installation.